# QT Vector QAction

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Стоит перед мной задача:

> Имеется примитивный текстовый редактор. Нужно добавить `QAction` для каждого нового файла, при нажатии на который(имеется ввиду нажатие на `QAction`) открывался тот самый файл.

```
    // QVector<QAction *> actionRecentFiles;
    actionRecentFiles.push_back(new QAction(currentFileName, this)); // добавляем в вектор QAction
    actionRecentFiles.back()->setData(currentFileUrl); // добавляем дата для того, что бы потом перейти по нему
    connect (/* здесь не понимаю как добавить все QAction из вектора */, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]()
    {
       // changeCurrentFile(const QString &); - меняет текущий файл
       changeCurrentFile(this->actionRecentFiles[actionRecentFiles.indexOf(/* тут так же не понимаю как найти тот самый QAction */)->data().toString());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял...

```
         actionRecentFiles.push_back(new QAction(currentFileName, this)); // добавляем в вектор QAction
         actionRecentFiles.back()->setData(currentFileUrl); // добавляем дата для того, что бы потом перейти по нему
         QAction* action = actionRecentFiles.back();
         connect (action, &QAction::triggered, this, [this, action]()
         {
            // changeCurrentFile(const QString &); - меняет текущий файл
            changeCurrentFile(action->data().toString());
         });
```